# Disable CTRL+Shift_Enter on IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, disable

When I am on IE, when I use tab to move my focus to the link and press CTRL+Shift+Enter, I get the page opened in another tab. I want to restrict this behavior on IE and show the message to user like "not supported", please suggest me how to achieve this using javascript.

Comment: Why are you pressing CTRL and SHIFT?

Comment: This is just to restrict the user from opening a new tab when user presses CTRL+Shift+Enter

Comment: You can listen for keyup and keydown events, detect when CTRL or SHIFT is pressed or released and keep track of their states (i.e. ctrl-down=true|false). Then on the links you want this behaviour, listen for click and keydown(enter) events and preventDefault() when CTRL or SHIFT is down, then change location to the link's href.

Comment: I suggest you refer this link may give you the idea of how to disable keys using Javascript. Ref: https://medium.com/@maheshkariya/disable-ctrl-key-right-click-and-f12-7617bb7f2e87

Answer (score 1):

You can try using keystroke events. On keystroke, alert the user & return false.

Reference :

[Disable Shortkeys when Ctrl or Shift clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933034/disable-shortkeys-when-ctrl-or-shift-clicked/13933117)`